# I would like to move an SKNode along a half oval path

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My scenario is that I am moving an existing node along an arch and would like it to stop once it reaches the other side. An easy analogy would be that I want to have something move along a rainbow.

My current code though does perform a proper oval, but it then continues underneath my y origin point to return back to its starting point. I understand that I can better control a circle to stop where I wish, but for my use case, a circular path will not work.

An abbreviated version of my code is:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: frame.width - 60, height: 100)
    let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange,
                           size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    box.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    addChild(box)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: 30, y: frame.midY)
    let rect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    let action = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath,
                                 asOffset: false,
                                 orientToPath: false,
                                 speed: 250)
    box.run(action)
}
```

The above code produces this when run:

[image]

My goal is for the orange box to stop once it reaches the left side.

I have looked through the various UIBezierPath initializers, and the only other one that looks promising is to use `UIBezierPath(cgPath:)`. Ideally, I would then need the `cgPath` to populate this to satisfy my criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was correct about the `UIBezierPath(cgPath:)` based approach.

The key piece for me was to run with the code posted in the question, but to then capture the contents of the `path` variable so I could extract the values from it. With these, I could then construct a hardcoded `CGPath` that I could then use.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .orange,
                           size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    box.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    addChild(box)
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let start = CGPoint(x: 345, y: 383.5)
    let end = CGPoint(x: 30, y: 383.5)
    let controlPoint = CGPoint(x: 190, y: 533.5)
    path.move(to: start)
    path.addQuadCurve(to: end, controlPoint: controlPoint)
    let action = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath,
                                 asOffset: false,
                                 orientToPath: false,
                                 speed: 250)
    box.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))
}
```

Finally, how it looks when used:

[image]

If I avoid the `repeat` on `SKAction`, it will complete with the object located precisely where I want it.

Since I am no expert on SpriteKit, I would be interested in finding out if there is a better way to approach this.

Comment: You shouldnt need that move to end, the path is already at end.  Although this does work,  you probably want a quadratic curve.... addQuadCurve with your control point being mid x

Comment: Also, if you use local coordinates (start at 0,0) and set as offset = true,  your repeat action will turn into a hopping effect

Comment: Thanks @Knight0fDragon. I updated the answer to use `addQuadCurve`. The return was because I had it close the path & removed that.